# domain regex for .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

Firstly, sorry for my bad English.
I want config my .htaccess to rewrite URL.

example.com/company1.com

instead example.com/sub=company1.com

My .htaccess now:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([a-z_]+)/?$ index.php?sub=$1
```

I was search in stackoverflow.
If i using (.*) regex for all charaters or ([a-z\.]+) for include "dot" character in domain string ( company1.con), my skin was broken.
My temporary solution is use ([a-z_]+) with http://example.com/company1_com instead 
http://example.com/company1.com
It's bad solution :(
So, please give me regex for this problem.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to prevent the `index.php` from looping:

```
RewriteEngine On
# let index.php pass through, thus stopping the rewrite loop
RewriteRule index.php - [L]
# route everything to index.php
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?sub=$1 [L]
```

You could also do a check for existing resources first. Since index.php exists, that would also break the loop. This would make it so if you're requesting static content like javascript or css, it won't get routed through index.php:

```
RewriteEngine On
# request isn't for an existing file or directory
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# route everything to index.php
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?sub=$1 [L]
```

Comment: Thanks @Jon Lin - `/index.php` made browser return "Object not found!" error but I try remove "/" and it run ok.

Answer (score 1):

Rewriting for Apache is described in [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule).

For you, as long as you ignore possible GET-parameters or paths, it should be

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/([^?/]+) /index.php?sub=$1 [L]
```

I guess it was broken because either you were missing the "/" before index.php, there is a longer path in GET ( example.com/company1.com/css/style.css ) or you submit a form ( example.com/company1.com?a=foo&b=bar ).

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?sub=$1
```